# Set Value NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsmutabledictionary

I am having trouble saving an NSMutableDictionary. I am trying to save it to NSUserDefaults, then load and change a blue, then save it again.

So I initially make it like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              firstNameLbl, @"firstName",
                              lastNameLbl, @"lastName", 
                              nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:d forKey:@"youDict"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then I load it and try and change a value like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"youDict"];
    [d setObject:textField.text forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:d forKey:@"youDict"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

However, this line, `[d setObject:textField.text forKey:key];`, causes the app to crash and I get this error:

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Comment: It seems that you can't do in this way, surely NSUserDefaults returns an immutable __NSCFDictionary, so may be the problem is when you call  `[d setObject:textField.text forKey:key];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

objectForKey returns an immutable value for NSUserDefaults. To make this work replace the first line of your 2nd code block with this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"youDict"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults doesn't distinguish between mutable and immutable objects, so when you get it back it'll be immutable:

If you want a mutable dictionary, just use mutableCopy:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"youDict"] mutableCopy];
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: SO needs to place a 15-minute limit or so before allowing anyone to accept an answer, to reduce the "first answer is always the best" problem.

Comment: Certainly agree with you...It's only way to reduce unnecessary iteration and pick up best answer for stack-overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code I think will we helpful for you.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ValueForKey:@"youDict"]];
```